# Flask: User input [POST]

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

When a user submits input, I'm trying to execute a script that takes the user's input as a parameter and redirects the user back to the home page. When I run the script below, everything seems to work with the exception of the redirection. When I hit submit in the web browser, I get No data submitted.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from Index_generator import index_generator
from Yelp_api import request_yelp

@app.route('/home_city',methods = ['POST'])
def home_city():
    CITY=request.form['city']
    request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=CITY) #This function executes the script
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

What if use `url_for` with `redirect`?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from Index_generator import index_generator
from Yelp_api import request_yelp

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    return 'Hello World'

@app.route('/home_city',methods = ['POST'])
def home_city():
    CITY=request.form['city']
    request_yelp(DEFAULT_LOCATION=CITY) #This function executes the script
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Mauro. For some reason, i'm still getting "No data received", "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.", and "Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE".  Hmmm

Comment: Put some debug like [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [`ipdb`](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb) could help you.